# Websphere Application server doesnt start

Tags: rad, websphere-8

Hello everyone Im going crazy trying to fix this problem. My WAS was working fine and my application was working. Today I had to update my application and for some reason I was getting an error and my appserver stopped working. So I created a new profile but now every time I try to start the server I get the following error. I searched around and it sounds like the port issue or an existing instance can someone please help me solve this. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Assuming that CORBA is running on the default port numbers then it might be worth running `netstat -ano` to see whether there is another process listening on ports 683 and 684. You might need to change the netstat arguments depending upon which OS you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded TCPview to check which port was still active once I closed the connection it was good to go!